# Integration $ f(x) = e^{1-e^{-x}}$

Tags: integration

Consider the function:

$ f(x) = e^{1-e^{-x}}$

The question:

> Find a number $M_1$ such that the area between the curves
>   $y=f(x),y=0,x=0,x=2$ is at most $M_1$

What I did:
[image]

We haven't learned yet the Exponential Integral function (saw online similar stuff), so I would like help without it..

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: $$M_1=2e{}{}{}$$

Comment: Tried taking $-t=\ln k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is asking for an *upper bound* for the integral, and there are many ways to do that other than evaluating the integral.  The fact that the integral can't be evaluated in elementary terms is a hint that you're probably not required to evaluate it.

One of the crudest estimates for an integral is: if $f(x) \leq M$ on $[a,b]$, then $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \leq M (b-a)$. So it is enough to find an upper bound for $f(x) = e^{1-e^{-x}}$ on $[0,2]$, then multiply by $2$.  This is what Did did when he arrived at his hint.